# Getting Bluetooth to Work After Moving Boot Camp Partition to New Mac

Tags: bootcamp, bluetooth

I had a Boot Camp partition with Windows 7 on my 2008-era MacBook Pro, and everything worked fine.

I have a new MacBook Pro. I partitioned it using the Boot Camp Assistant, and then I copied my old Boot Camp partition using Winclone.  After booting into Windows on the new Mac, I ran the Boot Camp Windows Support stuff, which supposedly installed current drivers.  Almost everything works fine: I have the hi-res display, trackpad works fine, sound works fine, etc.

However, Bluetooth isn't working at all.  When I try to add a device, no Bluetooth devices appear in the list.  In Device Manager, the "Apple Broadcom Built-in Bluetooth" icon has a yellow warning triangle on it.

I tried uninstalling that driver and then re-running the Boot Camp Windows Support setup, but I'm back to the same situation.

Any suggestions?  (Other than reinstalling Windows and all my Windows applications from scratch.)

Answer (score 6):

Apparently the problem is that the "Apple Broadcom Built-in Bluetooth" driver is not the right one for the new hardware.  Here's what I did to fix it:

- Open Device Manager, open the Bluetooth Radios subtree, right-click the "Apple Broadcom Built-in Bluetooth" icon, and choose the "Update Driver Software..." menu item.
- Choose "Browse my computer for driver software"
- Choose "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"
- Select "Apple Inc." for Manufacturer, and "Apple Built-in Bluetooth" for Model, and click Next.

After the driver installed, "Apple Broadcom Built-in Bluetooth" had been replaced by "Apple Built-in Bluetooth" and "Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator" in the Bluetooth Radios subtree of Device Manager, and I was then able to use the **Add a device** wizard to set up my Bluetooth mouse and keyboard.